# write data from database to node opcua-server

Tags: database, node-opcua

I have a node opcua server installed on my laptop. I want to write some data like x, y coordinates and time from a file or a device driver to the variables in my opcua server. I am new to javascript. Any help regarding this topic would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use node-red for solutions like these.
Node-RED is really helpful and easy in dealing with these kind of issues. You can easily connect your database using a node in Node-RED and then get the data on the server.